# _leaflet2.default.map is not a function

Tags: react-leaflet

I tried to run the react code sample from  https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/docs/Getting%20started.md, but I got "_leaflet2.default.map is not a function" error from next code in react-leaflet.js:

```
Map.prototype.componentDidMount = function componentDidMount() {
   var props = (0, _omit3.default)(this.props, ['children', 'className', 'id', 'style']);
   this.leafletElement = _leaflet2.default.map(this.container, props); //line with error
   ...
}
```

Link to my source code: https://github.com/sergeysibara/react-leaflet-test

Comment: Did you also install leaflet when you installed your packages?

Comment: Yes, I installed leaflet.  Possible it is necessary to change webpack configuration for leaflet and react-leaflet. But I do not understand what configuration is correct for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, Leaflet is not being required by any js file, so it is not getting loaded.

Add this line to the top of your index.js file:

```
require('leaflet')
```